# Regex code only allows a single space

Tags: javascript, regex, string, whitespace

I have this regex `(^[a-z]\s{1})+`. It is supposed to match only letters that are separated by a single space but it still returns true even with this input:

```
"a a    a"
```

I want it to reject the expression if it has two consecutive spaces.
Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, because it matches the first `a` with a space.

Comment: Please give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075

Comment: It appears you forgot to ask a question. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful and [off topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Fail that string match? Try `/^[a-z](?:\s[a-z])*$/`

Comment: Checking for two consecutive spaces would not require regex, `"a a     a".indexOf("  ") >= 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regex that fixes this: `^\s*([a-z]\s|[a-z]$)+\s*$`

**Explanation**:

- It matches the string up to the end (`$`) so it will discard your example line
- It matches the case when the string ends with a letter - `[a-z]$`
- It ignores leading and trailing spaces: `\s*` at the beginning and the end

You can play with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/hZ3hX6/2).